# Internal server error 500 when using Ajax and Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

When I use Ajax for sending a post request I get an internal server error 500 and couldn't find a solution.

Here is my view that contains the Ajax:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>upload</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/xhr2.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function(){

            $('#btn').click(function(){

              $.ajax({

                  url:"localhost:8000/test",
                  type:"POST",

                  dataType:'json',
                  success:function(data){
                  console.log(data);
              }
            });
           });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body> 

    <input type="text" name="username" id="txt">
    <input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="send">


   </body>

</html>
```

and here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
class UploadsController extends Controller
{
    public function getUpload(){
        return view('upload');
    }

     public function postTest($request request){
         return response()->json(['name'=> 'khaled','age'=>45]);
    }
}
```

and my routes:

```
Route::get('/upload','UploadsController@getUpload');
Route::post('/test','UploadsController@postTest');
```

When I click the button, it should send and asynchronous post request, but an error "internal server error 500" returns instead.

Comment: Are you sending token ?

Comment: Can you post your error log / stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the bug can occur because it is missing `csrf-token`

first, add  the meta : `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Then, configure the headers of the ajax requests :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

I hope it helped you

Comment: TokenMismatch error returns a 419 status code, not 500

Comment: Another question if you don't mind, when i upload large file (20-30 M), it stuck before completing, any idea ?

Comment: sorry in this question I can not help you

Answer (score 2):

Wrong parameter definition for `postTest` fuction

```
public function postTest(Request $request){

     return response()->json(['name'=> 'khaled','age'=>45]);
}
```